# Testing for two pairs in Poker Program

Tags: java

Can anyone point me in the direction of logic I should be thinking of when attempting to test if a poker hand of 5 cards has two pairs?

So far what I had before was pairing up each possible pairs of two of the five cards and returning true if two or more of these pairs have equal values. The problem I am having is that if there is three of a single card the method still returns true even if there are not two pairs.

Comment: Start with the strongest hands first then work towards the weakest hands.

Comment: For every value in your hand check that two cards have the same value, and no other card has this value. Then exclude that first value and do the same for the other cards

Comment: sort cards by value first. than it's easy to test them.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I started from the strong hands and ended up using a loop that said if it had three of a kind and didn't have a full house then to return false and it appears to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

There's 2 main groups of poker hand rankings.

1. Straights/flushes
2. Hands that have more than one card of a particular
   ranking (everything else)

In the everything else category one thing that you will notice is each time you have a stronger hand ranking it includes at least one type of weaker hand ranking when you take a combination of those cards.

For example AAAT9 is a 3 of a kind but it also includes a pair if you take two of the aces out.

The easiest way to find the strength of a hand is therefore to start from the strongest hand first then work downwards in the strengths categories, this matches the actual rules of the game very closely.